# Is it possible to send meta-commands to PostgreSQL through Unix TCP socket?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to be send meta-commands to PostgreSQL through Unix TCP socket?

Because I can query the DB, but when I try to send meta-commands like \d, \l, and so on, I am getting C42601 Message:

> syntax error at or near "\".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are commands implemented by `psql` only and they are not understood by the server. So there is no point sending them to the server.

If you want to find out which SQL statements `psql` uses for each of the meta-commands, start it with the option `--echo-hidden`. It then logs each SQL query that is used to implement the meta-commands.